# Creating a parameterized Type with multiple parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got the following datatype:

```
data HVF a b = HVF { h1 :: !a
                   , l1 :: !Int
                   } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Monoid (HVF a b) where {...}
```

And I try to write a function:

```
hvf :: (Num a, Ord a) => Fold a (HVF a b)
hvf = Fold tally summarize
  where
    tally x = HVF x

    summarize (HVF x y) = (HVF x y)
```

with

```
data Fold i o = forall m . Monoid m => Fold (i -> m) (m -> o)
```

but I get the error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Int -> HVF a b0’ with ‘HVF a b1’
  Expected type: (Int -> HVF a b0) -> HVF a b
    Actual type: HVF a b1 -> HVF a b
• In the second argument of ‘Fold’, namely ‘summarize’
  In the expression: Fold tally summarize
  In an equation for ‘hvf’:
      hvf
        = Fold tally summarize
        where
            tally x = HVF x
            summarize (HVF x y) = (HVF x y)
• Relevant bindings include
    hvf :: Fold a (HVF a b) (bound at src/Data/HVFScanner/HVF.hs:119:1)
    |
119 | hvf = Fold tally summarize
    |
```

which I don't understand, can anyone explain in english?

Additional info...

`Fold` is from https://github.com/Gabriel439/slides/blob/master/munihac/foldmap.md#-in-one-slide

Comment: The code you posted doesn't cause such an error, that apparently happens somewhere else in whatever code you're trying to compile. Make it an [MCVE] please, and post error messages in full.

Comment: Should mention its first haskell project, so could well be something simple I've done wrong.

Comment: What is `Fold`?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think that's a good edge of Haskell to start with. Existential quantification is a somewhat advanced topic (and indeed often considered not very idiomatic, though this particular use is rather nice).

Comment: Doesn't `tally x = HVF x` need an additional argument after `HVF x`?

Comment: Why did you change your code after I already posted my answer?

Comment: I just updated after chi pointed out

Comment: Your update changes nothing about `tally`. It still takes two arguments where it should only take one. However, you also changed the type of `hvf` and the definition of `summarize` (along with its type).

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you're saying about tally now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fold` takes two values, a `tally` function that injects an input value into some monoid, and a `summarize` function that extracts a result from the monoid.

Informally:

```
tally :: i -> m
summarize :: m -> o
```

where `m` is some `Monoid`.

In your code you have

```
hvf :: (Num a, Ord a) => Fold a (HVF a b)
hvf = Fold tally summarize
  where
    tally x = HVF x

    summarize (HVF x y) = (HVF x y)
```

Your `tally` has type `a -> Int -> HVF a b`, which (because `->` in types is right associative) is equivalent to `a -> (Int -> HVF a b)`. Thus the type checker assumes that your input type `i` is `a` and your monoid type `m` is `Int -> HVF a b`.

Your `summarize` has type `HVF a b1 -> HVF a b2`. However, to be used with `Fold tally`, it needs to have type `m -> o` where `m` is `Int -> HVF a b`. This is what the error message is complaining about: The type of `summarize`'s argument is `HVF a b1`, but `summarize` is used in a context where it needs to accept an `Int -> HVF a b`.

I don't understand the rest of your code, but I think you forgot an argument to `HVF` in `tally`. Maybe something like `tally x = HVF x 0`?

Answer (score 3):

The error actually lies in `tally`. That is supposed to have type `a -> m`, where the monoid is in this case `HVF a b`, i.e.

```
tally :: a -> HVF a b
```

but what you've implemented

```
tally x = HVF x
```

actually has type `a -> Int -> HVF a b`, because `HVF x` is still lacking the `Int` field, i.e. you've only *partially* applied the `HVF` value constructor, and due to the way Haskell works in *curried mode*, that lacking argument is automatically deferred as an extra argument to the `tally` function.

Somewhat curiously though, this in itself is *not* a type error: the signature `a -> Int -> HVF a b` has in fact *also* the form `a -> m`, but `m` is in this case the function type `Int -> HVF a b`. Indeed, that function type has a `Monoid` instance too!

But this then means that you'd also need the type

```
summarise :: (Int -> HVF a b) -> HVF a b
```

...but that isn't the type of `summarise`, it's just

```
summarise :: HVF a b -> HVF a b
```

hence the rather misleading error message.